# Angular CLI with AOT

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to run this repo

https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-starter

with ng build --prod --aot

but I am get following error

```
sh-3.2# ng build --prod --aot
Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
  0% compilingCannot determine the module for class Places in /Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/src/app/service/places.pipe.ts!
Error: Cannot determine the module for class Places in /Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/src/app/service/places.pipe.ts!
    at analyzeNgModules (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13079:17)
    at OfflineCompiler.compileModules (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13115:20)
    at CodeGenerator.codegen (/Users/iminar/Dev/angular/modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/codegen.ts:71:26)
    at AotPlugin._make (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:186:43)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:151:75)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsParallel (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:156:14)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:463:8)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsync (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:73:70)
    at Compiler.compile (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:456:7)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:219:10)
    at Compiler.readRecords (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:367:10)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:216:9)
    at next (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:81:11)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/webpack/lib/CachePlugin.js:34:58)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsync (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:85:13)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:213:8)
    at next (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:81:11)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/webpack/lib/node/NodeEnvironmentPlugin.js:23:3)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsync (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:85:13)
    at Compiler.run (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:210:7)
    at /Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/angular-cli/tasks/build-webpack.js:26:29
    at Class.run (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/angular-cli/tasks/build-webpack.js:25:16)
    at Class.run (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/angular-cli/commands/build.js:50:26)
    at Class.<anonymous> (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/models/command.js:152:17)
    at tryCatch (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/rsvp/dist/lib/rsvp/-internal.js:215:12)
    at invokeCallback (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/rsvp/dist/lib/rsvp/-internal.js:230:13)
    at publish (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/rsvp/dist/lib/rsvp/-internal.js:198:7)
    at flush (/Users/Picchu/Documents/smartangular2/node_modules/rsvp/dist/lib/rsvp/asap.js:85:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Solution:
Had double files one withiner service folder and one in pipe folder. Deleted the place.pipe from service folder.

Comment: Have u declared your places pipe in app.module.ts?

Comment: yes I daclared it in app.module.ts

Comment: See solution above